# Is there any way to "pagin" html tables hiding the last elements with Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm implementing a web application that uses Twitter.

I have one table with a single column that contains the tweets of the user. I want to limit the number of tweets of the table and hide the rest of it, and If the user wants, show more tweets. The concept similar to the official Twitter application.

I think that pagination is a wrong concept.

How can I do this with HTML and Angular js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `limitTo` filter available on `ng-repeat` to limit the initial load of data and after hitting the load more, you can load the next items.

Working Plnkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/CXYwDVJFYgje6tMdEKAq?p=preview

Following code will let you to add more tweets and once no more tweet left, it will change the button text as well.

**Snippet -**

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.data = [
  {id: 1, tweet: 'This is tweet 1 - ies, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing.'},
  {id: 2, tweet: 'This is tweet 2 - ies, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop .'},
  {id: 3, tweet: 'This is tweet 3 - ies, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus Papsum.'},
  {id: 4, tweet: 'This is tweet 4 - ies, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus versions of Lorem Ipsum.'},
  {id: 5, tweet: 'This is tweet 5 - ies, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.'},
  {id: 6, tweet: 'This is tweet 6 - ies, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus.'},
  {id: 7, tweet: 'This is tweet 7 - ies, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop.'},
  {id: 8, tweet: 'This is tweet 8 - ies, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently.'},
  {id: 9, tweet: 'This is tweet 9 - ies, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop.'},
  {id: 10, tweet: 'This is tweet 10 - ies, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop.'}
];

$scope.limit = 2;
$scope.showMore = function() {
  $scope.limit += 2;  
};

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <h3 ng-bind="title"></h3>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in data | limitTo: limit">
      <div style="margin: 5px;padding: 5px;border: 1px solid green;">{{item.tweet}}</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
  <button ng-click="showMore()" ng-bind="limit !== data.length ? 'Load More' : 'No More Tweets'"></button>
</body>

</html>
```